# How to find seg fault which doesn't occur when using tools

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, gdb, valgrind

I ask this because the seg fault doesn't occur in my C++ program if I run it with Valgrind or GDB. But it's easily reproducible once I run it stand-alone as it will seg fault without fail. I have commented out sections of code to the point of making it run, but I have still been unable to find the exact cause. I fear it's happening earlier on and just showing up late.

Update:
   To clarify, this is C++ 17 on Linux.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's way too large and if I knew what the problem was, I could minimize it for an example. I'm just looking for advice, steps and other thoughts to help find it.

Comment: An easy way is to write timestamps to a log file with the function name and line number.  This will give you a description of the behavior, while running close to full speed.  Some debuggers will initialize variables for you, so your seg fault may be due to an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Check any data structures that you are using. Maybe you are accessing something outside its bounds? Try clang++ sanitizer. Sometimes I have had better luck with that one.

Comment: Possibly a race condition?

Comment: Are all your compilation flags identical. e.g. are you doing `-O0` when debugging, and `-O2` otherwise?

Comment: I've been compiling with "-g -O0 -Wall" for Valgrind or -gdb with DBG.

Comment: What sort of visual-c (tagged) runs on Linux?

Comment: Sorry, got the wrong tag there. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're not disabling core dumps (`ulimit -c unlimited`, though there are [other config options](https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/enable-and-analyze-coredumps-in-linux) that are relevant), then when your program crashes, you should get a core dump file.

Run `gdb program core` to analyze the core dump -- gdb will look like you've used it to run your program and it hit the signal that stopped it.  You can do a backtrace to see the stack, examine variables and memory, etc.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Good</strike> bad old `printf` debugging :). Make your program drop breadcrumbs (in the form of console output, or writing to the log) in the general vicinity of the crash point. As you get a better idea of where the crash point is, make breadcrumbs tighter. Assuming your crash is reasonably deterministic, this will converge on the crash point eventually.

Another technique, install a signal handler for SIGSEGV. Once the signal fires, dump the crash point registers, then use something like `addr2line` to translate the IP address to the source line. You'd need the starting address of the module.

Comment: There is nothing good in printf debugging, except if one doesn't have a better alternative. That's why debuggers exist anyway, to avoid losing unnecessarily time.

Comment: And I completely agree. I was going for a nostalgic vibe here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typical race condition to me. Are you using any thread in your code? If so, consider using `std::mutex` when you access some data that might be used in other thread.
I always could debug such things only using TONS of debug prints, but beware, they also can slow down your code a bit and remove race condition.